# receiving a error "encountered the symbol .."?

Tags: oracle, plsql

getting error on code

```
           <TD CLASS="tablelabel">Base Currency</TD>
                        <TD class="reqlabel1">');
                          vSQl := 'select toValueText(a.code, a.descr) from (select currency_code code, des1 descr '||
                                                                              'from sy_curr_code 
                                                                              ) a ';
                     htp_dropdown(pvSql => vSQL,
                     pvName => 'pvcurrencycode',
                     pvDefVal =>' SELECT CurrCurrencyCode.INF_SRC_DB currency_code, DECODE(CurrCurrencyCode.currency_code,'AUS','USD','BPS')result from s_sales_center,'
                     -- pvDefVal =>NVL(CurrCurrencyCode.INF_SRC_DB,'BPS'),

                     pvEvent => 'style="width:200px" class="reqinput1" tabindex=33 id="pvcurrencycode"');
                 htp.p('</TD>
                 </tr>
   <TR>
```

I would think my code works,i have check if the right syntax and it seems right to me and i think having AUS there shouldnt be a problem and right now i get error on

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (6343: 132): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AUS" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is a little hard to tell given that what you have given us is mixed in with application code but I think you need to double quote all single quotes.

like this

```
            pvDefVal =>' SELECT CurrCurrencyCode.INF_SRC_DB currency_code, DECODE(CurrCurrencyCode.currency_code,''AUS'',''USD'',''BPS'')result from s_sales_center,'
```